# Conception: is my entity relation diagram correct?

Tags: django, entity-relationship

I want to develop an app in Django to follow user account for our different applications.
I have identify at least 3 entities:
- Projects
- Users
- Applications

I have amended my ER diagram.

A project can have many users (e.g. project 2 below).

A user can be implied in many projects (e.g. user 1 below).

A user implicated in a project can have access to many applications and access defined (e.g. users 1 and 2 below)

Examples:

- user 1 is implicated in project 1 and have access to applications 1 (write) and 2 (read)
- user 1 is implicated in project 2 and have access to applications 1 (write), 2 (write) and 3 (write)
- user 2 is implicated in project 2 and have access to applications 2 (read) and 4 (read)

Is this ER diagram is correct?

[image]

Comment: Pro tip: give meaningful and more verbose names for your columns/felds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A project can have many users. A user can be implied in many projects.

Yes, you should have used a many-to-many relation between the projects and users.

Thus, your EMR diagram should have a `*------*` (or a `N------N`) line between `projects` and `utilisateurs`.